# Как сравнить масивы по значению

Tags: c#

Есть Dictionary < int[], string > example_dictionary , при записи в него новой переменной мне надо проверить, существует ли уже данный ключ, но если делать так:

```
if (example_dictionary.ContainsKey(new int[] { ferst_cords[0], ferst_cords[1], second_cords[0], second_cords[1] }))
    //something...
```

то одинаковые по 'наполнению' массивы все равно показываются как разные.
Как сделать чтоб он работал по задумке?
Добавление в словарь:

```
example_dictionary.Add(new int[] { ferst_cords[0], ferst_cords[1], second_cords[0], second_cords[1] }, "hi");
```

Comment: Конструктор словаря принимает параметр comparer. Задайте свой компаратор для массивов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Как, если это поле доступно только для чтения?

Answer (score 3):

Класс `Dictionary` может в конструкторе принимать параметр comparer - компаратор, используемый для сравнения объектов в этом словаре.

Создадим класс для сравнения массивов:

```
class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Length;
    }
}
```

Используем его:

```
var arrA = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var arrB = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
var arrC = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var dict = new Dictionary<int[], string>(new ArrayComparer());
dict.Add(arrA, "A");
dict.Add(arrB, "B");
//dict.Add(arrC, "C"); // Exception
Console.WriteLine(dict.Count);

if (dict.ContainsKey(arrC))
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("no");
```

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```